# Time Complexity - Order of Growth

Tags: constants, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have just started learning the order of growth and found the below exercise in the text.

We have the below equation,

```
T(n) = 3n + 32n^3 + 767249999n^2 = O (?)
```

Usually, we drop the lower order terms and constants and we would get O(n^3). But in this case, the constant **767249999** is too large and that will make the n2 term bigger even with very large values of n. So, this relation results in O(n^2) or O(n^3)?
Thanks!

Comment: it is O(n^3) the constants are always dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It results in `O(n^3)`. This is due to the fact, that for large enough `n` (no matter if this is "small", "large" or "very large") the term `32n^3` dominates `767249999n^2`.

By the definition, you would need any constant `c` such that `cn^2` is never dominated by `32n^3` for this to be in `O(n^2)`. But this is impossible, as for `n > c/32` you will find out that `32n^3 = 32n*n^2 > cn^2`.